# Specify type as interface merged with a new property?

Tags: typescript, interface

In TypeScript, is it somehow possible to do something like this:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
}

interface Test {
  something: number;
  personWithVersion: IPerson & (version: string); // is something like that possible?
}
```

`personWithVersion` shall have the properties from `IPerson` and another property `version`. Can I somehow specify this without creating a new interface or do I have to create a new interface like `IPersonWithVersion`, which then extends `IPerson`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
}

interface Test {
  something: number;
  personWithVersion: IPerson & { version: string };
}
```